# Unkown error on Mysql Stored Function RETURN CAST(finNumber AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS final;

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

My question says everything. I have mysql stored function with return type decimal 12,2.

This is the whole code:

```
BEGIN
    -- The only edit is ony line number 9, 32 and 33

    DECLARE ctrNumber VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE finNumber VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE sChar VARCHAR(1); -- be aware varchar length is 1
    DECLARE inti INTEGER DEFAULT 1;

    SET @in_string = '.abc12';

    IF LENGTH(@in_string) > 0 THEN
        -- Loops from . to 1 (.abc1)
        WHILE(inti <= LENGTH(@in_string)) DO
            SET sChar = SUBSTRING(@in_string, inti, 1);

            -- Find if it contains the following array
            SET ctrNumber = FIND_IN_SET(sChar, '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.'); 

            -- If returns true or 1 or 2 or positive number it means it contains
            IF ctrNumber > 0 THEN
                SET finNumber = CONCAT(finNumber, sChar);
            END IF;

            SET inti = inti + 1;
        END WHILE;
        -- end of loop from . to 1
        RETURN CAST(finNumber AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS final;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;    
END
```

the error happens in the part:
`RETURN CAST(finNumber AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS final;`

The finNumber is `".12"` I convert it from string to decimal.

When I tried it on Stored procedure, using `SELECT CAST(finNumber AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS final;` it works fine.

You can copy my whole code with return type of decimal 12,2 and paste it in stored function/procedure.

I have tried it in both MySQL and MariaDB, it doesn't look like that's the case.

This is the error:

> The following query has failed: "CREATE FUNCTION `ExtractNumber`()
>   RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER
>   BEGIN -- The only edit is ony line number 9, 32 and 33 DECLARE
>   ctrNumber VARCHAR(50); DECLARE finNumber VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
>   DECLARE sChar VARCHAR(1); -- be aware varchar length is 1 DECLARE inti
>   INTEGER DEFAULT 1; SET @in_string = '.abc12'; IF LENGTH(@in_string) >
>   0 THEN -- Loops from . to 1 (.abc1) WHILE(inti <= LENGTH(@in_string))
>   DO SET sChar = SUBSTRING(@in_string, inti, 1); -- Find if it contains
>   the following array SET ctrNumber = FIND_IN_SET(sChar,
>   '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.'); -- If returns true or 1 or 2 or positive
>   number it means it contains IF ctrNumber > 0 THEN SET finNumber =
>   CONCAT(finNumber, sChar); END IF; SET inti = inti + 1; END WHILE; --
>   end of loop from . to 1 -- original code: remove CAST and UNSIGNED --
>   UNSIGNED removes all special chars or letters -- because CAST converts
>   number into INT or UNSIGNED -- RETURN CAST(finNumber AS UNSIGNED) AS
>   final; RETURN CAST(finNumber AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS final; ELSE RETURN
>   0; END IF; END "
>
> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'AS final; ELSE RETURN 0; END IF; END' at line 33

Comment: The message is pretty close try dropping the as final alias.

Comment: @P.Salmon just wow. haha thank you very much! did not saw that

Comment: @P.Salmon try putting it as answer so that this will have an answer thanks again!